# Nest for loop yield unexpected results? R

Tags: r

so I have this loop that is splitting the `iris` dataset into 3 sections as a list. I want to then print it out. The inner for loop does this fine. But my goal is to have some sort of progress bar that tells me what `n` in the list I am in.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this but this code below was the closest I could get to it. Although it prints the output 3 times or as many times as the outer loop.

```
n <- 50
#Does not load into session

nr <- nrow(iris)


z <- split(iris,
           rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, 
               length.out=nr))


for (j in 1:length(z)) {
  
  #Progress Message
  cat('Processing group number: ', j, 'of', length(z),'\n')
  
  #Nest for loop
  for (i in z){
    print(head(i,5))
  }
  
  #Complete Message
  cat('Completed process for group number: ', j, 'of', length(z),'\n')
  
}
```

## output

```
Processing group number:  1 of 3 
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
Completed process for group number:  1 of 3 
Processing group number:  2 of 3 
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
Completed process for group number:  2 of 3 
Processing group number:  3 of 3 
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
Completed process for group number:  3 of 3
```

My goal is to have the output be this

```
Processing group number:  1 of 3 
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
Completed process for group number:  1 of 3 
Processing group number:  2 of 3 
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
Completed process for group number:  2 of 3 
Processing group number:  3 of 3 
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
Completed process for group number:  3 of 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like once you've created the outer `for` loop you no longer need the inner one. Right now it's looping over each entry in the list `z` and printing it out when you really only want the one entry that the outer loop is currently processing. Here's your outer loop with that inner loop removed and replaced with an index to only grab the relevant entry from the list:

```
for (j in 1:length(z)) {
  
  #Progress Message
  cat('Processing group number: ', j, 'of', length(z),'\n')
  
  #Print the current group
  print(head(z[[j]]))
  
  #Complete Message
  cat('Completed process for group number: ', j, 'of', length(z),'\n')
  
}
```

and the output:

```
Processing group number:  1 of 3 
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
Completed process for group number:  1 of 3 
Processing group number:  2 of 3 
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
56          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
Completed process for group number:  2 of 3 
Processing group number:  3 of 3 
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
Completed process for group number:  3 of 3
```

Nicely asked question! Well done providing clear details and a reproducible example with expected output.